# Complete form with LWP::UserAgent in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to complete a form by post using the module [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) in Perl of melissadata page. The problem is never complete well fields and the request never completes, showing "normal page" without the desired result.

The code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $nave = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$nave->timeout(5);
$nave->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; nl; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201Firefox/2.0.0.12");

my $target = "5.135.178.142";

$re = tomar(
  "http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/iplocation.asp",
  { 'ipaddress=' => $target, 'submit' => 'Submit' }
);

if ( $re =~ /City<\/td><td align=(.*)><b>(.*)<\/b><\/td>/ ) {
  print "Found : $2\n";
}
else {
  print $re;
}

sub tomar {
  my ($web, $var) = @_;
  return $nave->post($web, [%{$var}])->content;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `mostrandose`?

Comment: sorry my bad english , my from is spain.

Comment: Guys! Please respect non-English speakers. A vote to close because of the language barrier is cowardly.

Comment: @adsdsa no need to apologize.  I just had no idea what you meant by that.  It's good to be as exact as possible here, so if you are able to run your questions through a spell checker before posting, that helps us to help you.  We all make typos. :)

Comment: The cause of your problem is the trailing = after ipaddress, it should be `'ipaddress' => $target`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for **why** your scraper doesn't work is that the website you are interested in uses Javascript, and LWP::UserAgent doesn't support Javascript.

For how to handle this, you have a couple of options.

1. Parse out the JS, and run it using [the Javascript package](http://search.cpan.org/~claesjac/JavaScript-1.16/lib/JavaScript.pm)
2. Use [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) and perl will automate firefox, and use it to process the JS
3. This is Perl (TMTOWTDI) find another package that can parse/process the JS  for you.

Comment: Remember that JavaScript is necessary only to generate the HTML form. If the contents of the form can be assumed then there is no need to involve JavaScript.